# Sql statement to linq conversion

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, linq, sql-to-linq-conversion

I want to get count of `Testhistories` using group by but through error when using linq. Without group by got the count but that was wrong.

This mysql query is working fine

```
SELECT 
    t.RecordId AS `Id`, t.Name, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*)
     FROM 
         (SELECT t1.PatientId, t1.RecordId
          FROM tbl_TestHistories AS t1
          GROUP BY t1.RecordId) AS t0  
     WHERE t.RecordId = PatientId) AS `TestCount`
FROM 
    tbl_Patients AS t
WHERE 
    t.DoctorId = '';
```

But when I tried to write linq for same query the statement was generated like below which is cause error

```
SELECT 
    `t`.`RecordId` AS `Id`, `t`.`Name`,
    (SELECT COUNT(*)
     FROM 
         (SELECT `t1`.`PatientId`, `t1`.`RecordId`
          FROM `tbl_TestHistories` AS `t1`
          WHERE `t`.`RecordId` = `t1`.`PatientId`
          GROUP BY `t1`.`PatientId`, `t1`.`RecordId`) AS `t0`) AS `TestCount`
FROM 
    `tbl_Patients` AS `t`
WHERE 
    `t`.`DoctorId` = '';
```

This is my attempt at the linq query:

```
var patients = (from patient in _dbContext.Patients.Include(x => x.TestHistories)
                where patient.DoctorId == doctorId
                select new PatientResponse
                        {
                            Id = patient.RecordId,
                            Name = patient.Name,
                            TestCount = patient.TestHistories.GroupBy(x => new { x.PatientId, x.RecordId }).Count()
                        });
```

Please share a linq query which returns the same result as the first SQL statement shown here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
var patients = (from patient in _dbContext.Patients.Include(x => x.TestHistories)  where patient.DoctorId == doctorId group new { x.PatientId, x.RecordId } by patient into g
       
        select new PatientResponse
                {
                    Id = g.key.RecordId,
                    Name = g.key.Name,
                    TestCount = g.Count()
                });
```

Comment: Query gives compile time error for groupby

Comment: I appreciate your efforts, but this also not work, as I described in question summary I want to apply group by on testhistory table.